# Selenium returns different html source than viewed in browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

Im trying to use Selenium to load next page with results by clicking Load More button from this [site](https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco).
However the source code of the html page loaded by selenium does not show(load) actual products which one can see when browsing. 
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

#browser = webdriver.Firefox()#Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
URL = "https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco"
PATIENCE_TIME = 60
LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@class = "kcl-btn ng-scope"]/span' 
caps = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Python3\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
caps["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'C:\Python3\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe',service_log_path=os.path.devnull,desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get(URL)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(20)
        html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
        print(html)
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH)


        loadMoreButton.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        break
print ("Complete")

driver.quit()
```

Not sure if I can attach sample html file here for reference.
Anyway, what is the problem and how do I load exactly the same page with selenium as i do via browser?

Comment: What do you mean by *the code returned by Selenium*?

Comment: @Guy The source code of the html page loaded by selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to the use of PhantomJS, it isn't maintained any more and deprecated from Selenium 3.8.1. Use Chrome headless instead.

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks. That returned the right content. Though now Im getting 2 other errors - </button> is not clickable at point (391, 579) and Element not interactable. I see some banner over the page. Can this be a problem?

Comment: @BillyJhon Yes. If the banner disappears automatically you can wait for it to disappear, have a look at [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits), something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "some id"))`. Otherwise you need to close it.